# How can i use Log.d to get what has passed to a variable in my activity, and where can i see the result?

Tags: android

Its a noob question, but i'd searched quite a while but i didn't understand

i really want to find what is the value that is passed to a variable..and where can i see the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you pass to Log.d goes to a text file on the device.  You can read it by downloading the file, or by running adb logcat in a terminal.  Or by using the DDMS tab in eclipse.